# TinyMCE in httpget retrieved Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to edit an object on my website. I click on a button and then the modal opens. In between the click and the showing of the modal, the object is fully retrieved and given to the partial view for the modal.

However, TinyMCE is not working in this modal. It does work on  every other modal I use (that does not use any HttpGet functionality).

First page view (where I can click on edit etc. I've omitted some code that is not relevant.)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/content/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit-button" data-id="@Model[i].id">Edit</button>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="edit-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery function called when clicking the button

```
  $('.edit-button').click(function () {
      var url = "/Admin/Edit"; // the url to the controller
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); // the id that's given to each button in the list
      $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
          $('#edit-container').html(data);
          $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
      });
  });
```

Finally the modal:

```
@model project.Models.Object

<script>tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"

});</script>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit</h4>
      </div>
                 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
         {
      <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg ">
                    <label for="ex2">Titel:</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class= "form-control input-lg"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-lg ">
                    <label for="ex2">Beschrijving:</label>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Description, new { @class= "form-control input-lg"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Opslaan</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
         }
```

So the issue is basically that the tinceMCE editor is not working on that textarea.